# Why is the Frankl conjecture hard?

Tags: co.combinatorics

This is a naive question that could justifiably be quickly closed.
Nevertheless:

***Q***. Why is
[Péter Frankl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture)
conjecture so difficult?

> If any two sets in some family of sets have a union that also belongs to the family, must some element belong to at least half of the sets in the family?

This has remained unsolved for ~$40$ years.
It seems that, unlike other conjectures (say, concerning prime conjectures), it has not been confirmed for vastly huge sets (just: families of at most $50$ sets).

More specifically, can anyone indicate why this conjecture seems so
difficult to prove or disprove? Why it has withstood assaults so long?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: This is an entirely apropos answer, and if you reformulate it as an explicit answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the conjecture is false, but the counterexamples are large with very little structure.

Comment: Apparently there are problems with argument in the preprint you just linked to. See for instance https://mathstodon.xyz/@tao/109829637016032856

Comment: @SamHopkins: Thanks, I was unaware of the problems. I deleted the reference.

Comment: Your formulation of PF's conjecture is a mess. Fortunately, the link that you've provided, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture, is fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

(**Migrated** by request from the comments.)

Bruhn and Schaud's (2013) [**The journey of the union-closed sets conjecture**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3297) provides a rather readable write-up. Particularly relevant is the section **Obstacles to a proof**; for example, you may check just after *Conjecture 15* in which the authors ask (essentially) your question here:

> "So, why then has the conjecture withstood more than twenty years of proof attempts?" (p. 14)

Bruhn and Schaud then list three possible techniques of proof, and go into a bit of detail around why they do not seem to work out; these techniques are: *injections*, *local configurations*, and *averaging*.

The paper also provides a few relevant re-formulations using, e.g., lattices, (maximal stable sets of bipartite) graphs, and the "Salzborn" formulation (p. 12). In each case, a re-formulation of the **Frankl** (or **union-closed sets**) **conjecture** brings corresponding ideas and techniques with varying potential; the authors of this particular survey do well by their promise early on:

> "The focus of this survey is on the methods employed to attack the conjecture. Our treatment of the literature is therefore somewhat uneven. Whenever we can identify a technique that, to our eyes, seems interesting and potentially powerful we discuss it in greater detail" (p. 3).

Comment: I find the "injection" argument and obstruction intriguing: There cannot be any singletons $\{x\}$ in a family violating the conjecture, as the map $S \to S \cup \{x\}$ is injective (hence $x$ lives in half the sets). There cannot be any two-element sets $\{x,y\}$ by a similar argument. But the argument breaks down for sizes $k \geq 3$.

Comment: Link appears to be broken. Is this the same as https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3297 ?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes: That is the same paper (and all page numbers correctly correspond). I've altered the link; thanks!